# Hyperledger Fabric Synchronize the ledger data of the different channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

If i create multiple channel and one partner is on the both the channel.
If the transaction of that partner happens in one channel , Is there way to sync the data in the ledger of both the channel ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not understand the conception channel. The channel is isolation ,different channels have their own ledger, and they do not sync the data each other.

Comment: I understand the channel concepts clearly. i need to sync the data of both the ledger because one org is in both the channel. I know it can be done by calling nested invocation call. I was asking about any efficient way to do that

Comment: Channel isolation is the important design of fabric. One partner join the two channel ,  if two channels have the common data to sync,  call nested invocation call.